# How would I use and implement a MaskedTextBox into my Calculator application? C#

Tags: c#, calculator, maskedtextbox

So I'm working on a calculator application in C-Sharp and I want to prevent people from entering more than 1 period/point at once. So they can't type "....." or "1..1" or "1.1.1"
Really just stuff like that.... I would also like to prevent them from adding alphabetical characters in by typing them in with the keyboard, characters like "a, b, c".

I was told to use a MaskedTextBox, and I want to know if that is correct. Also, if it is correct, how would I implement it into my code? I'm a complete beginner when it comes to C#, so I would like some help (toned down for a beginner).

So far the code I have written is:

```
    double total1 = 0;
    double total2 = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnOne.Text;
    }

    private void btnTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnTwo.Text;
    }

    private void btnThree_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnThree.Text;
    }

    private void btnFour_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnFour.Text;
    }

    private void btnFive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnFive.Text;
    }

    private void btnSix_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnSix.Text;
    }

    private void btnSeven_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnSeven.Text;
    }

    private void btnEight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnEight.Text;
    }

    private void btnNine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnNine.Text;
    }

    private void btnZero_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnZero.Text;
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Clear();
    }

    private void btnPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        total1 = total1 + double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
        txtDisplay.Clear();
    }

    private void btnEquals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        total2 = total1 + double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
        txtDisplay.Text = total2.ToString();
        total1 = 0;

    }

    private void btnPoint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnPoint.Text;
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void txtDisplay_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

So I ask... how/where do I add in this "MaskedTextBox" - if that is correct? How do I implement it? What makes it work?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using WinForms or WPF? It looks like WinForms but you should tag it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `MaskedTextBox`, since you're simulating the keypad with your buttons.  Just put something like this in `btnPoint_Click`:

```
private void btnPoint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)     
{         
    if (!txtDisplay.Text.Contains("."))
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnPoint.Text;    
    } 
}
```

Comment: The question *did* refer to people typing in characters.

Comment: True. I was not paying attention.

Comment: This did solve my main problem, so thanks for that! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: No problem - friends don't let friends use the `MaskedTextBox`. :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to MusiGenesis's snippet, you can use the KeyPress event of the text box to prevent non-digits and multiple periods.

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if(char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || ((e.KeyChar == '.' && textBox1.Text.IndexOf(".") < 0) ) )
    {
        textBox1.Text += e.KeyChar;
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

or set `ReadOnly` property of the text box to `true`.

Comment: This will fail if the cursor is in the middle of text already entered.

Comment: And to add to Bala's snippet: this will only work if textBox1 has the focus, which it won't anymore the first time you click one of the buttons. Since you presumably want to get the keyboard presses no matter what, you can instead set the form's `KeyPreview` property to `true`, and add a handler to the *form's* `KeyPress` event (and put Bala's code in it).

Comment: @Greg the cursor position won't matter. Since e.Handled is set to true, the characters are appended manually *only* in this event handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can also save a big amount of code if you write the code of the click event just once and asign the click event handlers of every number buttons to it:

```
    private void btnNumber_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is Button)
            txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + ((Button)sender).Text;
    }
```

So you can save all of the following methods

```
private void btnZero_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) (...)
private void btnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) (...)
.
.
.
private void btnNine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) (...)
```